# CSV upload to MySQL leaving carriage return

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I've managed to get my upload CSV to MySQL working.

But I'm facing a problem where when it uploads the list after every entry it adds a return at the end:

```
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];

$handle = @fopen($file,"r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 125000)) !== false) {
        $import="INSERT into test_mysql (uid, number) values (UUID(), '$buffer')";
        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: suggest validating your input

Comment: don't use `@`. it's the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalalalalala can't hear you". never suppress errors that way. always have proper error handling.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).